# Output a multi select with selected values from an array?

Tags: php

I have an array of jobs:

```
$jobs = ['j1', 'j2', 'j3', 'j4', 'j5'];
```

I also have an array of user jobs:

```
$userJobs = ['j1', 'j3'];
```

I'm outputting a multi select of all the jobs and I wish to have user jobs selected.

If a user only had one job i would do something like this:

```
foreach($jobs as $job){
    echo '<option '.$job == $userJob ? 'selected' : ''.'>'.$job.'</option>';
}
```

But how to approach this comparing array without lots of loops?

Comment: `in_array()` or probably something with `array_intersect()`

Comment: `in_array($job,$userJob)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just flip the `$userJobs` array

```
$userJobs = array_flip(['j1', 'j3']);
```

then you can check with a simple `isset($userJobs[$job])`:

```
foreach($jobs as $job){
    echo '<option '.(isset($userJobs[$job]) ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$job.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a question of looking a value (the job) in an array (the user jobs).

```
echo '<option '.(!in_array($job, $userJobs) ? null : 'selected').'>'.$job.'</option>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use in_array - Checks if a value exists in an array

```
echo '<option '.(in_array($job, $userJobs) ? 'selected' : ''.'>'.$job.'</option>';
```